# How to add values by checking checkbox and remove value when unchecking checkbox

Tags: c#

I am working on a restaurant ordering system and i am using checkboxes so the customer can pick their chosen food. I am new to c# and would like when a checkbox is checked the price for the food is added to a textbox showing subTotal, i want to do this for each of my checkbox so the customer can check to add a value and uncheck it to remove the value. I don't exactly know how to code this. The pictureBox code is already working showing the picture of the food when checked and not showing when unchecked.

I have tried using subTotal.Text += 3.50; and subTotal.Text += 0; but that just adds onto the textbox.

```
private void checkBox1_CheckedChanged_1(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (checkBox1.Checked == true)
    {
        pictureBox1.Visible = true;
        pictureBox1.BringToFront();
        subTotal.Text += 3.50;
    }
    else
    {
        pictureBox1.Visible = false;
        subTotal.Text += 0;
    }
}
```

All my checkboxes should be able to add on their price when checked and remove their price when unchecked.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It isn't working because `subTotal.Text` is a string. You can't add integer/double to a string, you need to convert it first :

```
subTotal.Text = Convert.ToDouble(subTotal.Text) + 3.50;
```

But this piece of code will fail in some cases, like if subTotal.Text is empty.

You should try to have a global double variable totalPrice and add value to it :

```
totalPrice += 3.50;
subTotal.Text = totalPrice.ToString();
```

Comment: Thanks the code helps, but when i undo the checkbox the number remains the same in the subTotal textbox and when i check it again it just adds onto it. Is there a way to fix this?

Comment: When you uncheck the checkbox, then `checkBox1.Checked` is `false`. So you are in the `else` part of your test. Now you just have to substract the price instead of adding it. I'm not giving you the exact code but i'm sure you'll be able to figure it out :)

Comment: woow that was easy, thanks for the help, appreciate you helping out :)